# datetimeformatter joda parse multiple utc formats with optional millis

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to parse multiple possible UTC timeformats using joda with the following:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter;
        DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
        builder.append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.sss"));
        builder.append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss"));
        formatter = builder.toFormatter();
        formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime("20130122-12:01:59"));
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20130122-12:01:59" is too short
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
    at com.cme.clearing.financials.gateway.internal.config.Sample.main(Sample.java:16)
```

Is there any way to ask joda to parse optional millis in UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
// Milliseconds parser
final DateTimeParser msParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendLiteral('.').appendDecimal(millisOfSecond(), 1, 3)
    .toParser();

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();

builder = builder.appendFixedDecimal(year(), 4)
    .appendFixedDecimal(monthOfYear(), 2)
    .appendFixedDecimal(dayOfMonth(), 2)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendFixedDecimal(hourOfDay(), 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendFixedDecimal(minuteOfHour(), 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendFixedDecimal(secondOfMinute(), 2)
    .appendOptional(msParser); // <-- HERE: optional milliseconds
// builder.build().withTimeZone(DateTimeZone.UTC) will return the formatter
```

Of course, adapt to your code, but that should be pretty easy.

Edit: adapted to OP's demand

Comment: This formatter will not print in joda-time >= 2.2. Is there a way to get the exact same behaviour, but allow printing (discarding the millis)?

Comment: @juell I'll have to investigate; I'm not sure which version of Joda Time I'm using

Comment: I posted this as a separate question just now: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921105/print-from-joda-time-datetimeformatter-with-optional-parser , please answer there if you figure it out :)