# Print from joda-time DateTimeFormatter with optional Parser

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In a project using joda-time 2.1, I have the following `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
   /**
   * Parser for the "fraction" part of a date-time value.
   */
  private static final DateTimeParser FRACTION_PARSER =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .appendLiteral('.')
          .appendFractionOfSecond(3, 9)
          .toParser();

  /**
   * A formatter for a "local" date/time without time zone offset
   * (in the format "yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss[.fff]").
   */
  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_LOCAL =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.date())
          .appendLiteral('T')
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond())
          .appendOptional(FRACTION_PARSER)
          .toFormatter()
          .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

It does exactly what I want. It parses dates with or without fractions, and prints them without fractions.

If I upgrade to a more recent version of joda-time, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Printing is not supported
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.toPrinter(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:136)
```

So I guess what I had before was an error, but it did exactly what I wanted to do! How do I get the same behavior, without making an error? I've tried using `append(DateTimePrinter, DateTimeParser[])` with a null printer and with a printer that doesn't actually print anything and neither of them work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "neither of them work"? What happens in each case?

Comment: `public DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendOptional(DateTimeParser parser) Appends just a parser element which is optional. With no matching printer, a printer cannot be built from this DateTimeFormatterBuilder. `

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOptional%28org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser%29

It was a bug which was fixed in 2.2 http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto220.html

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I know - but this is still the behavior that I want and it's not clear how to implement it now that the bug is fixed.

Comment: @JonSkeet the printer that didn't print anything (just an empty string literal) could not be created (same exception as above). If I pass a null printer to append(DateTimePrinter, DateTimeParser[]), the resulting DateTimeFormatter is not a printer and will refuse to print later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out, the solution is to construct the complete parser and printer separately, like so:

```
  /**
   * Parser for the "fraction" part of a date-time value.
   */
  private static final DateTimeParser FRACTION_PARSER =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .appendLiteral('.')
          .appendFractionOfSecond(3, 9)
          .toParser();

  private static final DateTimeParser BASE_PARSER =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.date())
          .appendLiteral('T')
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond())
          .appendOptional(FRACTION_PARSER)
          .toParser();

  private static final DateTimePrinter BASE_PRINTER =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.date())
          .appendLiteral('T')
          .append(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond())
          // omit fraction of second
          .toPrinter();

  /**
   * A formatter for a "local" date/time without time zone offset
   * (in the format "yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss[.fff]").
   */
  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_LOCAL =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .append(BASE_PRINTER, BASE_PARSER)
          .toFormatter()
          .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use the printer. Would this work for you? It compiles and outputs the correct date/time for me.

```
private static final DateTimeParser FRACTION_PARSER =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLiteral('[')
                .appendLiteral('.')
                .appendFractionOfSecond(3, 9)
                .appendLiteral(']')
                .toParser();

/**
 * A formatter for a "local" date/time without time zone offset
 * (in the format "yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss[.fff]").
 */
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_LOCAL =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(ISODateTimeFormat.date())
                .appendLiteral('T')
                .append(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond())

                .appendOptional(FRACTION_PARSER)
                        .toFormatter()
                        .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

String strInputDateTime = "1990-12-11T13:12:22[.025]";

DateTime dt = FORMAT_LOCAL.parseDateTime(strInputDateTime);

System.out.println(dt);
```

From reading the Javdoc there is a mention of toParser(); not being used and instead to use toFormatter(); I hope this helps.

> toParser
>
> public DateTimeParser toParser()
>   Internal method to create a DateTimeParser instance using all the appended elements.
>   Most applications will not use this method. If you want a parser in an application, call toFormatter() and just use the parsing API.
>
> Subsequent changes to this builder do not affect the returned parser.
>
> Throws:
>   UnsupportedOperationException - if parsing is not supported

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html

This might be more usefull actually

> public DateTimeFormatter toFormatter()
>   Constructs a DateTimeFormatter using all the appended elements.
>   This is the main method used by applications at the end of the build process to create a usable formatter.
>
> Subsequent changes to this builder do not affect the returned formatter.
>
> The returned formatter may not support both printing and parsing. The methods DateTimeFormatter.isPrinter() and DateTimeFormatter.isParser() will help you determine the state of the formatter.
>
> Throws:
>   UnsupportedOperationException - if neither printing nor parsing is supported

Comment: appendOptional() takes a parser only, though - how can I specify a formatter as optional?

Comment: Can you post the code that uses the printing function?

Comment: It's pretty much just 
FORMAT_LOCAL.print(new DateTime(timeMillis.longValue(), zone);
The code in the OP fails on static instantiation of the Formatter, though, not on usage.